# Parsing logs to be sent to Elasticsearch

Tags: apache, elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

How to parse the below log pattern and split it bu space?
Is grok useful in that case or logstash modules?
any recommendations

### Log Pattern:

<[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <> <> <1518423645538>  <[LeaseClient] requesting renew leases [LeaseMessage renew_leases, leaseNames [service.SINGLETON_MASTER, service.CP_ManagedServer_1 (migratable)], owner -3099658339144629803/CP_ManagedServer_1, leaseTimeout -1, healthCheckPeriod 30000, gracePeriod -1] from LeaseServer [CP_ManagedServer_1,1517308775138]>

Comment: If your log doesn't vary from line to line, the [dissect](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.4/plugins-filters-dissect.html) filter could be a good idea (easier to work with, faster). For the `LeaseMessage renew_leases, leaseNames [service.SINGLETON_MASTER,...`, the [kv](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html) is a good fit if you want to extract the key-values pairs.

Comment: Thanks. this really helps

Comment: Also for grok, you can test your patterns there: http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match and find the common patterns there: https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns